# Showing PhpMyAdmin database in iOS uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a app in which I want to fetch data from PhpMyAdmin database to my `UITableView`.

Is there any good tutorial for this purpose? Please not any chat app tutorials I simply want to display my table in tableview.
My table has 5 fields (id, fname, lname, email, address).

Thank you

Comment: You would need a PHP layer(service component) in between your database and iPhone app.

Comment: yes i know i already have that part coded but have no idea how to fetch data and show in uitableview

Comment: Voted to close as asking for off site resource and/or library. You shouldn't be asking for off site resources like tutorials and such so this is the reason for my vote to close and my -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle it is to create a JSON API for your database and then make your iOS app parse the JSON data.

[Here is an example](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSON-example.php) of how to create a JSON output from MySQL using PHP.

When you have your JSON output you should download it from the app using the `NSURLConnection`and `NSJSONSerialization`, something like this:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://yourapi.url/here"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError **error = nil; 
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:error]];

NSInteger httpStatus = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
NSLog(@"responsecode:%d", httpStatus);

NSDictionary *parsedJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errorInfo];
```

The content of your JSON will be placed in the `parsedJson` dictionary.
This is just a quick example of using a synchronous request with `NSURLConnection`. If you want a asynchronous solution you should read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on `NSURLConnection`.

To show the data in a `UITableView` you should checkout [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/).